# facing error in flutter on Android version 11

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, flutter, exception

**Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError abstract method "android.view.WindowInsets android.view.WindowInsetsAnimation$Callback.onProgress(android.view.WindowInsets, java.util.List)" android.view.View.dispatchWindowInsetsAnimationProgress**

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1256], locale en-IN)
• Flutter version 1.22.5 at D:\FlutterSDK\flutter
• Framework revision 7891006299 (5 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
• Engine revision ae90085a84
• Dart version 2.10.4

Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 47.0.2
• Dart plugin version 193.7361
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

Answer (score 1):

I have also face the same issue in Android 11.

Below workaround working for me.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66232#issuecomment-749281680

On your app-level `build.gradle` add this to your `buildTypes > release` section

```
shrinkResources false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Along with the `build.gradle` file create a `proguard-rules.pro` file if not exist and add:

```
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.editing.** { *; }
```

Answer (score -1):

run in cmd or terminal and accept all licenses and again run a project

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```